# drop table from outside?

Tags: mysql

A poorly designed script ran on my MySQL 5.6 instance for 24 hours before I stopped it by killing the MySQL command line client and rebooting the machine while the script was still running.  The script created a new table and then inserted at least 70 million rows of data into the new table.  Now `service.msc` in windows 7 will not start MySQL as a windows service.  It gives error 1053.

How can I get MySQL to launch as a windows service?

Here is what I have done do far:

```
Deleted the ib_logfile* files  
Deleted the myservername.err file  
Changed the following settings in my.ini:  
    innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 100M
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
    innodb_log_file_size = 50M  
Restarted the computer a few times, trying to start the MySQL windows service a few times
```

I notice the size of the ibdata1 file is 76,812,288 KB

I have thought to just delete the newly created table, which would reduce the size of the database by a huge factor and get things back to what they were before the bad script ran.  It would be nice if I could just drop the table without opening the mysql windows service, or somehow bring the database back to the state it was in just before the script started running, and then just restart the windows service without the damage that is causing it not to start now.  But I do not know how.  Can anyone show me how to get windows to start the MySQL service again?

I uploaded the myservername.err file to a file sharing site.  You can read it [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/8r78Gi0NkkJY9iPZvKqa?b=SwKu8Q8PFoY86PYV2ZJg).  Please understand that this error file continues to grow into hundreds of megabytes in size.  The file sharing site just has the first few megabytes.  I imagine it gets repetitive after that.

Comment: You deleted `myservername.err`. A restart of Windows should have triggered an attempt MySQL startup. See if `myservername.err` exists. If it does, please post the output of the lines showing why MySQL dies.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I will work on this right now and post a response.  It may take a few minutes because I need to reboot my machine a couple times.  The myservername.err file is too big to open in notepad++, even though I deleted it.  And the new log files are each 100MB.  I am gonna repeat my steps above then report back with the error logs.  Please wait for me if you can.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I uploaded the `myservername.err` error log to a file sharing site and put a link to it at the end of my original posting above.  Does it help you see the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your data is corrupt. You might attempt starting the server iterating through the http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html documentation. If it starts you can attempt to save the large table (mysqldump/mydumper export) or drop it if it's not needed.